# Can't install xfce due unmet dependency

Tags: apt-get, debian-wheezy, xfce4

i wrote a CD with an iso-image from debian.org. the **debian-7.5.0-amd64-CD-1.iso**
from this [folder](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.5.0/amd64/iso-cd/).

Debian Wheezy 7.5 stable 64bit

There was an error at **Select and install software** step.

It said Retrieving file 770 from 800 and then it failed the installation.

I continued the instal and when i opened the computer it doesn't work the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> as i waited.

It starts at tty1 and after logging in i edited config file cause it had a lot of errors and said *E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages* or *Couldn't found the package*.

**FILE: /etc/apt/sources.list**

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.5.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 CD Binary-1 20140426-13:37]/ wheezy main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.5.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 CD Binary-1 20140426-13:37]/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
```

After that i tried to install xfce4 as desktop environment. Guide found at [Linux Panda](http://linuxpanda.wordpress.com/2014/03/02/guide-how-to-install-debian-8-jessie-xfce-using-netinst-minimal-iso-step-by-step-with-pictures/)

But it print at terminal:

[image: ***image>http ://i.stack.imgur.com/QD5vD.jpg (it doesn't let me post image. so someone fix it)***]

What i sould do? How i can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that even trough you installed "wheeze" you have "squeeze" repositories in your `sources.list` file. This shouldn't be! Just fix this up and everything should be ok:

```
sudo sed -i 's/squeeze/wheeze/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get check
```

And do not mix different repositories.

Comment: i found the solution. i forgot to change the sources.list to wheezy :P

Comment: @GeoMind that's exactly what I'm saying....